# Sorting based on one key then having the value of another key chain onto the first key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

```
vm.testComments = [
    {
        commentId: 1,
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        commentId: 2,
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        commentId: 3,
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        commentId: 4,
        parentId: 2
    },
    {
        commentId: 5,
        parentId: 1
    }
    ,
    {
        commentId: 99,
        parentId: 4
    }
    ,
    {
        commentId: 100,
        parentId: 4
    }
    ,
    {
        commentId: 101,
        parentId: 1
    }
    ,
    {
        commentId: 102,
        parentId: 5
    }
    ,
    {
        commentId: 103,
        parentId: 99
    }
    ,
    {
        commentId: 104,
        parentId: null
    }
];
function _orderComments() {
    var comment = vm.testComments.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
        if (comment[i].parentId == null) {
            comment[i].parentId = 0;
        }
    }
    comment.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.parentId - b.parentId || a.commentId - b.commentId; 
    })
    return comment;
 }
```

Hello, I am currently having issues with sorting by having the first keyvalue be referenced by the second keyvalue. It should be so that the 'commentId' should append to the matching 'parentId'.

Something along the lines of 1<-3/5/101  &   2<-4<-99/100.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide also the result of sorting of initial `vm.testComments` array... Just what you want to see at the end.

Comment: Your code looks like it should order the array by `parentId` and then by `commentId`, and when I ran it that's exactly what happened (noting that the function returns a new array containing references to the same objects, it doesn't modify the original array). It's not clear what other result you expected.